# Connecting raspberry pi to CPU via HDMi and getting display on monitor

Tags: pi-2

I was wondering if there's a way to get the Pi display on a computer monitor by connecting the Pi to PC via HDMi.

To make my question clear, I've attached a picture (It looks horrible though). Please refer to the picture

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC2qo.png]

Comment: This does not make much sense unless you replace the "CPU" in the middle with "computer" -- in which case the answer would be yes if the computer has an HDMI *input.*  Good luck finding that; HDMI took over in an eye blink because it was a collaboration between manufacturers and the recording industry (and entities which span both, such as Sony) to incorporate DRM features into the delivery system.   I.e., they really, really, really don't want people doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Why not directly connect the Pi to the monitor using HDMI? What the heck are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have seen people do this with capture cards in their PCs so that they can record the output, but most capture cards will also allow for a pass through mode that will allow you to Connect your Pi to it then your pc to your monitor. Although a capture card like this can cost you from $300 up to thousands

Comment: @DarthVader I was just wondering if I/anyone could do that. Well I'm just trying to achieve one thing here. Suppose you don't have a spare mouse(m) and a keyboard(k) and the m and k connected to your computer has ps2 port. Can we control the pi using the m and k connected to the PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this would not work unless your computer accepts HDMI input and can use that as a stream which you can direct to the monitor (via VLC maybe).

Have you considered directly connecting the Pi to the monitor? or VNC?

Comment: I have connected my Pi directly to my monitor and also i've tried connecting via VNC. I was just curious if there's was a third alternative. Thanks :)

Comment: @ChandanNaik Do mark as answer if this answered your question :)